# Address already in use... Linux web server on Node

Tags: node.js, express, server

I am running a web server on linux and I am trying to access my app remotely on a browser. However I keep getting the same issue when I run nodemon. The address/port is already in use.

The issue started using port 3000. It started up fine but any request made to the server made it crash, with the same output: "Port already in use."

I've tried changing the port many times.
I've tried to route it to my web domain with port 80. 
I'vet tried to PREROUTE a >1024 port to port 80. 
I've tried re-installing dependencies and restarting server.
All to no avail.

Here is how I start my server using express:

```js
const app = express(),
  server = require('http').createServer(app);
  
const port = 80 || 8080;

server.listen(port, "[address]");
```

As you can see the port is in use according to my ss -npl log. What else can be causing this problem?

Here are the some logs for more info:
[nodemon log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR3uR.png)
[address:port log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xch9U.png)

EDIT: A lot of times the server will start just fine and crash as soon as it receives a request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all not point of `port = 80 || 8000`. It will always be `80`. And for the problem, as you are using linux, the ports < 1024 are restricted by default. You either have to specify a port greater than that or grant `sudo` privileges to your server.

You can refer to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

Another approach is to redirect the port `80` to some other ports. You can run the following command to do that:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
```